# How to solve JSONdecode error in ajax django?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, http-post

I'm receiving JSONdecode error when sending the POST request from ajax to django views.py. The POST sends an array of json. The data from this POST will be used to create the model. Appreciate for any hints.

Error:

```
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /order-confirmation
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request information:
USER: ledi12

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data
```

AJAX Request:

```
var new_array = JSON.stringify(array)
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/order-confirmation',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{"array":"' + new_array+'"}',
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.d);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
      });
```

Views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def order_confirmation(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(r"request.body").read()
        print(data)
        return HttpResponse(status=200) 
    else:
        return render(request, 'main_templates/order_confirmation.html')
```

Comment: Don't create JSON with string operations, use `data: JSON.stringify({array: array})`

Comment: `r"request.body"` should just be `request.body`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks again sir ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the JSON library is not able to properly compile the string. There are a couple of things that your code needs to change. Remove 'r' character which is near request.body(). There is no need for 'read()' function in json.loads(). You can preprocess your array into a string and once done, and pass it to ajax. The data field will only have the string. So the ajax code field should look like

```
data: new_array
```

Comment: @husa Did you figure it out?